# Generate sum at bottom of results

Tags: sql

I have a query I have put together in SQL Server 2005 that calculates our volume by state:

```
SELECT ISNULL(q1.state,'UK') AS 'State', ISNULL(q1.TP,0) AS Transportation, ISNULL(q2.TL,0) AS Translation
    FROM
    (select p.state, count(Distinct t.patientID) as TP
     from v_trip t
     LEFT JOIN v_patient p ON t.patientid = p.ssn
     where t.transtype not like 'translati%'
     and created >= '5/18/2014'
     and created < '5/25/2014'
    group by p.state) AS q1
    LEFT JOIN
    (select p.state, count(Distinct t.patientID) as TL
     from v_trip t
     LEFT JOIN v_patient p ON t.patientid = p.ssn
     where t.transtype like 'translati%'
     and created >= '5/18/2014'
     and created < '5/25/2014'
    group by p.state) AS q2
    ON q1.state = q2.state
    ORDER BY q1.state
```

The results display a sum of volume in each state, and I'm trying  to get a total to calculate and enter at the bottom of my results. I have tried `ROLLUP` but it breaks the query, probably because I'm not sure where to properly place it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was unable to figure out how to total within the query for the final output to CSV, I went on to research the possibly in VB script.
I was able to total the columns of my report by adding the following lines to my VB script:

```
'Write header lines
line = "Report For Week of " & (dateadd("d",-7,sDate)) & ""
objTS.WriteLine line
line = "State,Data1,Data2"
objTS.WriteLine line

'Write detail lines
Do while not rs.eof
line = rs(0) & dl & rs(1) & dl & rs(2)
objTS.WriteLine line
if rs(1) >= 0 then
    gtpTot = gtpTot + rs(1)
end if
if rs(2) >= 0 then
    gtlTot = gtlTot + rs(2)
end if
rs.movenext
loop

'Output grand totals
line = "Grand Total," & gtpTot & dl & gtlTot
objTS.WriteLine line
```

This code adds a new line at the end of the file that displays the full totals for my data.